ROS2 foxy pcl remote visualization
I faced a proble to connect my remote rover to my host laptop through a VPN and i solved it by using Cyclone with this custom profile
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CycloneDDS xmlns="https://cdds.io/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://cdds.io/config https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/master/etc/cyclonedds.xsd">
    <Domain id="any">
        <General>
            <NetworkInterfaceAddress>ztzlgp434l</NetworkInterfaceAddress>
            <AllowMulticast>false</AllowMulticast>
            <MaxMessageSize>65500B</MaxMessageSize>
        <FragmentSize>4000B</FragmentSize>
        </General>
    <Discovery>
        <Peers>
            <Peer address="[ROBOT_VPN_IP]"/>
            <Peer address="[HOST_VP_IP]"/>
        </Peers>
        <ParticipantIndex>auto</ParticipantIndex>
    </Discovery>
        <Internal>
            <Watermarks>
                <WhcHigh>500kB</WhcHigh>
            </Watermarks>
        </Internal>
        <Tracing>
            <Verbosity>severe</Verbosity>
            <OutputFile>stdout</OutputFile>
        </Tracing>
    </Domain>
</CycloneDDS>

Now, i use velodyne VLP16 as laser scanner and i would like to visualize the pcl remotely on rviz2. What happens is that i can easily visualize the laser scans, but when i try to visualize the PCL nothing appears on rviz (the global frame is correctly set, i can see the laser scans), even if i try a ros2 echo nothing happens and, after a while, the nodes running on the robot machine disappears, i cant ros2 node list them and at some point also the ssh connection falls, i have to close the terminal and start a new ssh connection, but sometimes i have to restart the VPN service too otherwise i cant connect to the remote robot.
what i can do from my laptop is just ros2 topic info -v /velodyne_points It seems that the data to transfer is really huge and it afflicts the connection.
Any thoughts?? Maybe i need to adjust the custom profile?? Thank you
